# angular http.post input with ng-repeat and input with no ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel-5

can anyone help me? In my code, I have a form which user have to input, but the value is not all of the data. So, I have put the ng-repeated value for the data that has been input before. And, I want to post it using angular but the ng-repeated data is return "undefined".

Is there any cure for this? Here is my code

```
<form class="sky-form" ng-submit="formDataDiri()" name="datadiriForm" novalidate>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-12"><img src="images/icon_namapasien.png" alt=""/> Nama Pasien</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-12">
            <label class="input disabled" ng-repeat="data in dataDiri">
                <input type="text" value="{{data.name}}" placeholder="{{data.name}}" name="name" ng-model="nama" disabled="">
            </label>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /row -->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-12"><img src="images/icon_tgl.png" alt=""/> Tanggal Lahir</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-4">
            <label class="input disabled" ng-repeat="data in dataDiri">
                <input type="text" value="{{data.birth_day}}" placeholder="{{data.birth_day}}" name="name" ng-model="nama" disabled="">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-5">
            <label class="input disabled" ng-repeat="data in dataDiri">
                <input type="text" value="{{data.birth_month}}" placeholder="{{data.birth_month_name}}" name="name" ng-model="nama" disabled="">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-3">
            <label class="input disabled" ng-repeat="data in dataDiri">
                <input type="text" value="{{data.birth_year}}" placeholder="{{data.birth_year}}" name="name" ng-model="nama" disabled="" >
            </label>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /row -->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-12"><img src="images/icon_gender.png" alt=""/> Jenis Kelamin</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-12">
            <div class="select">
                <label class="select">
                    <select name="JKelamin" ng-model="jeniskelamin" required="">
                        <option value="">Pilih Jenis Kelamin</option>
                        <option value="1">Pria</option>
                        <option value="0">Wanita</option>
                    </select>
                    <i></i>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /row -->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-12"><img src="images/icon_alamat.png" alt=""/> Alamat</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-12">
            <label class="input disabled">
                <input type="text" value="" ng-model="alamat" name="address" required=""/>
                <input type="hidden" name="name" value="0" ng-model="kodekota">
            </label>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /row -->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-12"><img src="images/icon_telp.png" alt=""/> Nomor Telepon / Hp</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-12">
            <label class="input disabled">
                <input type="text" value="" ng-model="notelp" name="hp" required="" minlength="6" maxlength="13"/>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /row -->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-12"><img src="images/icon_layanan.png" alt=""/> Layanan</div>
    </div>

    <div class="tabform">
        <ul class="tabs" ng-model="layanan">
            <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-1" ng-click="homeservice()"> <span class="homeservice">Home Service</span></li>
            <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-2" ng-click="periksalab()"><span class="periksalab">Periksa di Lab</span></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col col-12"><img src="images/icon_tgl.png" alt=""/> Tanggal Pemeriksaan</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label class="input disabled">
                        <input type="text" ng-model="hs" class="datepicker1" />
                    </label>                                    
                </div>
<!--                                                <div class="col col-4">
                                                    <label class="select">
                                                        <select name="tanggalPeriksaHS" ng-model="dateperiksa" required="">
                                                            <option value="">Tanggal</option>
                                                            <option ng-repeat="n in range(1,31)" value="{{n}}">{{n}}</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                        <i></i>
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col col-5">
                                                    <label class="select">
                                                        <select name="bulanPeriksaHS" ng-model="monthperiksa" required="">
                                                            <option value="">Bulan</option>
                                                            <option value="01">Januari</option>
                                                            <option value="02">Februari</option>
                                                            <option value="03">Maret</option>
                                                            <option value="04">April</option>
                                                            <option value="05">Mei</option>
                                                            <option value="06">Juni</option>
                                                            <option value="07">Juli</option>
                                                            <option value="08">Agustus</option>
                                                            <option value="09">September</option>
                                                            <option value="10">Oktober</option>
                                                            <option value="11">November</option>
                                                            <option value="12">Desember</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                        <i></i>
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col col-3">
                                                    <label class="select">
                                                        <select name="tahunPeriksaHS" ng-model="yearperiksa" required="">
                                                            <option value="">Tahun</option>
                                                            <option value="2016" selected>2016</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                        <i></i>
                                                    </label>
                                                </div> -->
        </div><!-- /row -->

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-12"><img src="images/timeperkiraan.png" alt=""/> Perkiraan Jam Home Service</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-12">
                <label class="select disabled">
                    <select data-ng-options="h.id as h.time for h in dataHomeService.home_service_time" name="gender" ng-model="jamlayanan">
                    </select>
                    <i></i>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /row -->

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-12"><div class="smallprice">Tambahan biaya home service  Rp <span>0.00</span></div></div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content current">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-12"><img src="images/icon_tgl.png" alt=""/> Tanggal Pemeriksaan</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label class="input disabled">
                <input type="text" ng-model="periksa" class="datepicker2" />
            </label>

<!--                                                <div class="col col-4">
                                                    <label class="select">
                                                        <select ng-model="dateperiksa" required="" name="tanggalPeriksaPL">
                                                            <option value="">Tanggal</option>
                                                            <option ng-repeat="n in range(1,31)" value="{{n}}">{{n}}</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                        <i></i>
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col col-5">
                                                    <label class="select">
                                                        <select ng-model="monthperiksa" required="" name="bulanPeriksaPL">
                                                            <option value="">Bulan</option>
                                                            <option value="01">Januari</option>
                                                            <option value="02">Februari</option>
                                                            <option value="03">Maret</option>
                                                            <option value="04">April</option>
                                                            <option value="05">Mei</option>
                                                            <option value="06">Juni</option>
                                                            <option value="07">Juli</option>
                                                            <option value="08">Agustus</option>
                                                            <option value="09">September</option>
                                                            <option value="10">Oktober</option>
                                                            <option value="11">November</option>
                                                            <option value="12">Desember</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                        <i></i>
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col col-3">
                                                    <label class="select">
                                                        <select ng-model="yearperiksa" required="" name="tahunPeriksaPL">
                                                            <option value="">Tahun</option>
                                                            <option value="2016" selected>2016</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                        <i></i>
                                                    </label>
                </div> -->
            </div><!-- /row -->
        </div>
    </div><!-- /tabform -->

    <hr class="lineform" />
    <button class="btn-yellow" type="submit" name="submit" ng-disabled="datadiriForm.$error.required">Lanjutkan Pemeriksaan</button>
    <span ng-show="datadiriForm.$error.required"><center>Mohon mengisi dengan lengkap terlebih dahulu</center></span>
</form>
```

Here is my angular code for post:

```
$scope.formDataDiri = function(){
        alert($scope.nama);
        if($scope.layanan == '0'){
          $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: '/api/v1/order/datadiri',
          data:{
            nama_pasien: $scope.nama,
            birth: $scope.year + "-" + $scope.month + "-" + $scope.date,
            gender: $scope.jeniskelamin,
            address: $scope.alamat,
            city_code: "0",
            phone: $scope.notelp,
            service: $scope.layanan,
            //test_date: $scope.yearperiksa + "-" + $scope.monthperiksa + "-" + $scope.dateperiksa,
            test_date: $scope.hs,
            service: $scope.layanan,
            test_date_day: $scope.dateperiksa,
            test_date_month: $scope.monthperiksa,
            test_date_year: $scope.yearperiksa,
            home_service_times: $scope.jamlayanan,
            code: $scope.survey,
            jawaban: $scope.lainnya
          }
        }).success(function(data,status){
          $scope.dataPasien = data;
          //alert($scope.nama);
          $window.location.href = 'doctor/order/lab';
        });
        }else{
          $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: '/api/v1/order/datadiri',
          data:{
            nama_pasien: $scope.nama,
            birth: $scope.year + "-" + $scope.month + "-" + $scope.date,
            gender: $scope.jeniskelamin,
            address: $scope.alamat,
            city_code: "0",
            phone: $scope.notelp,
            service: $scope.layanan,
            //test_date: $scope.yearperiksa + "-" + $scope.monthperiksa + "-" + $scope.dateperiksa,
            test_date: $scope.periksa,
            service: $scope.layanan,
            test_date_day: $scope.dateperiksa,
            test_date_month: $scope.monthperiksa,
            test_date_year: $scope.yearperiksa,
            home_service_times: $scope.jamlayanan,
            code: $scope.survey,
            jawaban: $scope.lainnya
          }
        }).success(function(data,status){
          $scope.dataPasien = data;
          //alert($scope.nama);
          $window.location.href = 'doctor/order/lab';
        });
        }
```

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: formDataDiri function has no parameter ($scope.formDataDiri = function()), but yet you call it with parameter (ng-submit="formDataDiri(data)")

Comment: Another thing, why didn't you use ng-repeat for whole form? Then on submit send that data variable and it will be defined

Comment: Hi, @ImantsVolkovs as I said before, not all of the data are stored in my backend... so in this case there are only 2 data is presented which is the name and the birth date value...

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any where in your controller, you are using `$scope.data`, replace your view in `ng-repeat` with `dataPasien`.

```
<label class="input disabled" ng-repeat="dataPasien in dataDiri">
   <input type="text" value="{{dataPasien.name}}" placeholder="{{dataPasien.name}}" name="name" ng-model="nama" disabled="">
</label>
```

Comment: Hi @Thalaivar I have done this but when I use $scope.nama which is following the ng-model binding, the value returns undefined...

Comment: That is my problem until now

Comment: Can you tell me what does the http response date returns... data

Comment: basically in your response, you have to set $scope.name = data.nama